# How to create an .exe file from JAR that contains both GUI and Console tasks running Parallely?

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar, launch4j

I wrote a program which takes input from a client and does necessary parsing and sends to the console and also to the GUI app. Both of the processes run simultaneously in threads. Now I have to create a .exe file from JAR file. I tried using Launch4j and Jar2exe. But I am confused how to do and what to select. I have the options like:

1) console
2) GUI app
3) Service

Previously I wrote a client - server program, for which I used console but it doesn't contain any GUI part. Now I am really stuck with this. Can anyone help me in creating a .exe file from a JAR file that contains both GUI and also Console task.

Comment: The .exe will be just a wrapper that runs your .jar. If your .jar opens a GUI window and a console on execution so the .exe will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> Excelsior JET 14.0  or greater

to create .exe files from .jar file.

It works pretty good. i am using it myself.